# Unity3D Installation In Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: android, windows, graphics, unity-game-engine

I've installed latest version of unity in my windows 7 Ultimate desktop.

But while I'm launching the application it shows a warning as below

[image]

then shows an Error saying "*fatal error! failed to initialize unity graphics* "

[image]

I checked my desktop is running windows 7 ultimate with Directx11 and 
with a video card (Standard VGA Graphics Adapter).

Error report after above error dialog.

```
"System:
  OS: Windows 7  (6.1.7600) 64bit
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2120 CPU @ 3.30GHz, count: 4
  Physical RAM: 1960 MB
  Addressable RAM: 2048 MB

D3D9:
  no D3D hardware acceleration

OpenGL:
  Version: 1.1.0
  Vendor: Microsoft Corporation
  Renderer: GDI Generic
  VRAM: 64 (via fallback)
  Extensions: GL_WIN_swap_hint GL_EXT_bgra GL_EXT_paletted_texture

User locale: en-US
System locale: en-US

Running processes:
chrome.exe (1968)
    path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
    company:  Google Inc.
    product:  Google Chrome
    filedesc: Google Chrome
    filever:  34.0.1847.137
    prodver:  34.0.1847.137
chrome.exe (2588)
    path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
    company:  Google Inc.
    product:  Google Chrome
    filedesc: Google Chrome
    filever:  34.0.1847.137
    prodver:  34.0.1847.137
chrome.exe (1940)
    path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
    company:  Google Inc.
    product:  Google Chrome
    filedesc: Google Chrome
    filever:  34.0.1847.137
    prodver:  34.0.1847.137
chrome.exe (2604)
    path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
    company:  Google Inc.
    product:  Google Chrome
    filedesc: Google Chrome
    filever:  34.0.1847.137
    prodver:  34.0.1847.137
chrome.exe (2476)
    path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
    company:  Google Inc.
    product:  Google Chrome
    filedesc: Google Chrome
    filever:  34.0.1847.137
    prodver:  34.0.1847.137
chrome.exe (552)
    path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
    company:  Google Inc.
    product:  Google Chrome
    filedesc: Google Chrome
    filever:  34.0.1847.137
    prodver:  34.0.1847.137
chrome.exe (2716)
    path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
    company:  Google Inc.
    product:  Google Chrome
    filedesc: Google Chrome
    filever:  34.0.1847.137
    prodver:  34.0.1847.137
chrome.exe (2648)
    path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
    company:  Google Inc.
    product:  Google Chrome
    filedesc: Google Chrome
    filever:  34.0.1847.137
    prodver:  34.0.1847.137
chrome.exe (2460)
    path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
    company:  Google Inc.
    product:  Google Chrome
    filedesc: Google Chrome
    filever:  34.0.1847.137
    prodver:  34.0.1847.137
chrome.exe (2852)
    path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
    company:  Google Inc.
    product:  Google Chrome
    filedesc: Google Chrome
    filever:  34.0.1847.137
    prodver:  34.0.1847.137
chrome.exe (940)
    path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
    company:  Google Inc.
    product:  Google Chrome
    filedesc: Google Chrome
    filever:  34.0.1847.137
    prodver:  34.0.1847.137
chrome.exe (1576)
    path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
    company:  Google Inc.
    product:  Google Chrome
    filedesc: Google Chrome
    filever:  34.0.1847.137
    prodver:  34.0.1847.137
chrome.exe (2680)
    path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
    company:  Google Inc.
    product:  Google Chrome
    filedesc: Google Chrome
    filever:  34.0.1847.137
    prodver:  34.0.1847.137
chrome.exe (296)
    path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
    company:  Google Inc.
    product:  Google Chrome
    filedesc: Google Chrome
    filever:  34.0.1847.137
    prodver:  34.0.1847.137
Unity.exe (3320)
    path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe
    company:  Unity Technologies ApS
    product:  Unity
    filedesc: Unity Editor
    filever:  4.3.4.31067
    prodver:  4.3.4.31067
UnityBugReporter.exe (3472)
    path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\UnityBugReporter.exe
    company:  Unity Technologies ApS
    product:  Unity Bug Reporter
    filedesc: Unity Bug Reporter
    filever:  4.3.4.31067
    prodver:  4.3.4.31067
"
```

Dxdiag output.

[image]

Comment: Try running as Administrator? Also, http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/10517/failed-to-initialize-3d-graphics.html

Comment: I've checked the answer, My system is 32bit and dxdiag shows "Direct3D Acceleration Not Available.", Hope It will work fine if I'm  changing it to 64bit.

Comment: Please read each tags before using them. The unity tag is completely different from unity3d.

Comment: The first warning is because the project was created using an older version of Unity, so no problem. For the error, it seems that you are having a driver problem, try reinstalling the video driver.

Comment: My Video driver is upto date. :( ,I ve updated the question with error report.

Comment: I Installed Video driver from manufacturers website, now it is working fine.

Comment: How did you manage to do it if your video driver was already up to date? :D

Comment: Windows was showing as the VGA is uptodate , I checked the system configuration in dell website then performed online check on my system for missing drivers then downloaded the driver which is missing.:)